# Sufficient condition to conclude joint pmf equals the product of marginal pmf's?

Tags: random-variables, independence

Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ with marginal probability mass functions $f$ and $g$ respectively and with joint pmf $h$. Also, $E(\cdot)$ denotes the expected value.

It is true that if $f(x) g(y) = h(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$ then $E(X)E(Y) = E(XY)$?

But the question is whether, if $E(X)E(Y)=E(XY)$ then $f(x) g(y) = h(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)$?

Comment: The arguments of $f$, $g$ and $h$ should not read $X$, $Y$ and $(X,Y)$ respectively.

Comment: I have edited the question to correct the arguments.

Comment: Incompletely, it seems, so I gave a hand. (Also, note that PMF stands for probability *mass* function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=-1$, $0$, or $1$, each with probability $1/3$. Let $Y=X^2$.

The $E(XY)=E(X^3)=0$ and $E(X)=0$, so $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

However, $\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1)\ne \Pr(X=1,Y=1)$.

Comment: Replace $\Pr(XY=1)$ by $\Pr(X=1,Y=1)$.

Comment: @Did: Thank you, done.